# jQuery foreign font selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am doing an update of an old system. The users are used to selecting the foreign language they want to use, then selecting from a grid of character buttons. All I need to do is harvest what language and the id of the character buttons they selected and I can format it to what the database expects.

The end result is some english text with a little foreign text in the middle. The original code is VB6 so it was using the windows character grid from the font file. I'm really just looking for ideas on how I could access that same grid from a web app(JSP/JavaScript/jQuery). If I can do this I won't have to force the applications that displays this data to change how it translates to its screen.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about but posting some code might be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the info you have in the database is UTF-8 encoded and then when you generate the jsp's make sure they are UTF-8 encoded. You will also need to encode the javascript files to UTF-8 if you are going to load UTF-8 information through them. 
The users can continue to use the character map from windows, but if the character map needs to be part of the page you will need to create a component on your own.

For building the character map you would need to play around with [getCharAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and [fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) methods on String but it can be done, similarly to the following snippet:

```
var base = '\u0410'.charCodeAt(0)
var res = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    $('#main').append($('<span>').text(String.fromCharCode(base + i)));
}
```

full example at http://jsfiddle.net/vlahupetar/dr272/1/

Also take a look at [MDN's Unicode guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Unicode)